# create complex gremlin-java query

Tags: gremlin, titan

I have model implemented in titan graph database with relations presented below:

```
[A] ---(e1)---> [B] <---(e2)--- [C] ---(e3)---> [D]
 |      |        |       |       |      |        |
prop:id |    prop:number |       | label:e3      |
        |                |    prop:id            |
   label:e1         label:e2                 prop:number
    prop:prop1
```

`A` and `B` are "main vertices" (for example users), vertices `B` and `C` are "less important vertices" describing some data connected with users.

The input for the query algorithm is property `id` of vertex `A`.

I want to find all such vertices `D`, that are connected with `A` in the manner shown above. What's more I want to remember the property `prop1` of the edge `e1` between `A` and `B`.

More precisely, I want to efficiently retrieve pairs `(prop1, numberD)` where `prop1` is the property of edge between `A -> B` (if the edge has this property), and `numberD` is the property `number` from `D`.

I don't know how to efficiently implement this query.

It is easy to retrieve only vertices `D` (using `GremlinPipes`):

```
pipe
.start(startVertex)
.outE("e1")
.inV().hasProperty("number")
.inE("e2")
.outV().hasProperty("id")
.outE("e3")
.inV().hasProperty("number");
```

But problems occur when I need to get also edges `e1` and match them with vertices `D`.
I tried to compute all these steps separately, but is seems to be very inefficient.

Do you have any suggestions how to implement this (maybe using several queries) using gremlin-java or gremlin-groovy?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Pattern Match Pattern described here:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Pattern-Match-Pattern

```
startVertex.outE('e1').as('e')
.inV().hasProperty('number').inE("e2")
.outV().hasProperty("id")
.outE("e3")
.inV().hasProperty("number").as('d')
.table(t)
```

This should give an iterator of maps

`[e:e1, d:D]`

From each of these maps, you can easily extract the properties you are interested in.